# Replace class name after a delay

Tags: jquery

I ma generating table where each `<td>` has **class="A"**

```
<td class="A">
```

now how to replace class **A** with class **B** after some delay using jquery? so that after delay output will be

```
<td class="B">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('td.A').delay(500).attr('class', 'B');
```

or

```
$("td.A").delay(500).queue(function(next){
    $(this).attr("class", "B");
    next();
});
```

Comment: No it is not necessary to add queue because $('td.lock_temp').delay(500).attr('class', 'lock'); really works fine on both GC & FF

Comment: and what about for
<td class="OK A_tmp Fine"> to <td class="OK A Fine">

Answer (score 4):

```
// Change class from A to B after 1000 ms
setTimeout(function() {
  $("td.A").removeClass("A").addClass("B");
}, 1000);
```

Comment: thanks it is also fine but it apply class with left to right sliding effect